# Excel 2013 App Crash - Browser Not Supported

Tags: excel, office-2013

I have an Excel 2013 .xlsm workbook that has multiple tabs. One tab contains an App I created.

On the machine which I created the workbook, everything works perfectly fine. However, when I test on other machines, one of them provides a strange error. If I click on the tab that contains the App, the app starts to load, but there is an error:

> APP ERROR:
>
> Sorry, we couldn't load the app because your browser version is not supported. Click here for a list of supported browser versions.

The machine has multiple browsers installed, including Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 10 (version 10.09200.17183); update versions: 10.0.23 (KB3008923).
Crash details are provided below. Has anyone else encountered this before? How do you correct the problem?

Thanks,

```
Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   IEXPLORE.EXE
Application Version:    10.0.9200.17183
Application Timestamp:  546ebc2a
Fault Module Name:  urlmon.dll
Fault Module Version:   10.0.9200.17183
Fault Module Timestamp: 546ebc5a
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   000098b2
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding that this may be resolved with the user account profile within Excel. Ensure an account is signed in and may need to create a Microsoft account to access the Apps, even if locally developed.